# Gatsby develop command is running forever

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am now building Front end project using `Gatsby`.
It worked well.
But on windows, I am getting these error when i run `gatsby develop` and dev-server never starts.

```
verbose gatsby-source-prismic - creating node {"id":"61XXX","type":"PrismicImage","prismicId":"XXXX"}
verbose gatsby-source-prismic - creating node {"id":"7XXX","type":"PrismicLandingPage","prismicId":"XXXXs"}
⠇ source and transform nodes
⠼ gatsby-source-prismic - create nodes
⠸ gatsby-source-prismic - write out type paths
```

Anyone has idea why this is happening?

Comment: It seems stuck in creating node from `prismic` data.

Comment: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/docs/docs/debugging-the-build-process.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GATSBY_CONCURRENT_DOWNLOAD=50 gatsby develop
```

By default it's set to 200.

Comment: Where we need to set it ?

Comment: you can set to the npm script or use .env file @Tarun